# Python function which recognises when to convert coordinate system

Tags: python, coordinates, pyproj

How do I write Python code for an AWS lambda function which will convert easting and northings to longitude and latitude?

For example, if a CSV is uploaded into an S3 bucket it may contain either eastings/northings or longitude/latitude columns for the location of different features. I'd like to create a Python code which recognises this and knows what to do... e.g.

```
if in long/lat format = leave and move on to next function
else:
if in easting/northing then convert to long/lat and move on to next function
```

So far, I have my working Python code which will convert the eastings and northings to longitude and latitude (see below). Next I just neeed to write a function that recognises when to do this conversion.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:27700') #British National Grid
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') #WGS84
x1,y1 = 357551,259776 #(x,y coordinates)
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1) # convert to long/lat
print (y2,x2)
```

**edit**
The CSV that is uploaded to the S3 bucket has the following headers for ease of reference.

| Feature | Easting | Northing | Length | Date | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Feature1 | 181016.6 | 32794.39 | 6.5 metres | 17/01/2020 |  |

Comment: Unless your upload includes information about what CRS some data is in, there is no real way to infer the correct transformation to apply (e.g. 27700→4326). So to do a correct projection, information about the CRS is mandatory, at which point then you already "know" when to do the transformation: any time the input CRS is not 4326.

Comment: _If_ you know that input data can only have either CRS 27700 or 4326, then you could try inspect values. But if 27700 is only one of several possible input CRSs, then this won't work well.

Comment: @alphabetasoup At present, the data will only ever be in the CRS 27700. It is coming in the form of easting and northing columns, but I require 4326 longitude and latitude which is why I'm converting it for later geometry in postgis purposes

Comment: What's the format of the CSV values?  Just numbers; degrees symbol?  If just numbers, then you're out of luck.  You can test to see if they are within the -180 to 180 and -90 to 90 range and if they are not, then they are projected coordinates (eastings, northings), not geographic coordinates (lat/lon).  But that's not certain either, because the projected CRS also includes that range of coordinates.  You could narrow it down further to the geographic coordinates that just cover that projected CRS (see https://epsg.io/27700 ), but same problem still exists, just to a lesser extent).

Comment: @SonofaBeach Please see edited question to show the CSV format

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two possible CRS inputs, and one is a projected system in meters whereas the other one is in decimal degrees, have you thought about using a regex pattern to determine whether the input is one or the other?

Here's how you would detect a decimal degree input. Feel free to update the pattern if your input is DMS or something else. Constructing a regex pattern for a metric system is considerably simpler, but depends on the min max bounds of that particular system.

```
import pandas as pd
import re


pattern = r'[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)'
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df['dd'] = df['lat'].astype(str) + ',' + df['lon'].astype(str)
for i in df['dd']:
    if re.match(pattern,str(i)):
        print('coordinate {} is in decimal degrees'.format(i))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with regex pattern. I tried your code there with my CSV file and it didn't appear to work sadly

Comment: Mind pasting a few lines of the CSV with both types of coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WGS 84` bounding box to determined if `WGS 84` or `EPSG:27700`. I got it from https://epsg.io/27700

```py
# Considering easting = lon and northing = lat
if easting >= -8.82 and easting <= 1.92 and northing >= 49.79 and northing <= 60.94:
    print("Probably in lon, lat, don't do anything")
else:
    print("Probably in EPSG:27700, so do use your reprojection stuff")
```

I've also checked where are located the bounding box in `WGS 84` to be sure you could not have `EPSG:27700` points with these coordinates. Probably not except if your data are related to boats positions (corners are in sea area) as you can see if you follow below links

- South East corner (coordinates [-8.82 49.79](https://epsg.io/map#srs=27700&x=-8.82&y=49.79&z=7&layer=streets))
- North West corner (coordinates [1.92 60.94](https://epsg.io/map#srs=27700&x=1.92&y=60.94&z=7&layer=streets))